# Formula to calculate if a point is on a dash or a gap

Tags: math, drawing

I'm looking for a formula to check if a point on a dashed line of any length either falls onto a dash or gap.

My approach is to use the following formula

```js
/**
 * @param t The point to check
 * @param dash The length of a dash
 * @param gap The length of a gap
 */
function isOnDash(t, dash, gap) {
  const verticalOffset = 1 - gap / (dash + gap);
  const period = (2 * Math.PI) / (dash + gap);
  const phase = Math.asin(-verticalOffset) / period;

  return Math.sin(period * (t + phase)) + verticalOffset >= 0;
}
```

This nearly works, but it's not 100% accurate. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6kwfj8gd/) that shows this approach in comparison to a drawing a dashed line on a HTML canvas element.

Comment: Why use `sin`? I don't understand. What angles are you considering? Isn't the line always horizontal?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your problem, `return (t % (dash + gap)) < dash;` should be enough.

Comment: I used sin to have a periodic function, but the approach with the modulo works much better. If you don't mind turning it into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Oh! That's actually clever. In mathematics this can sometimes be a fun trick. Fourier even believed `sin` to be the answer to everything ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an arithmetic problem, not a problem with continuous numbers. As much as possible, you should avoid floating-points and functions like Math.sin or floating-point division, which will unavoidably result in approximation errors.

Instead, **modulo** is a simple arithmetic answer to your problem.

```js
/**
 * @param t The point to check
 * @param dash The length of a dash
 * @param gap The length of a gap
 */
function isOnDash(t, dash, gap) {
  return (t % (dash + gap)) < dash;
}
```